# Кодировка в HTML

Tags: кодировка, html, php

Вопрос от совсем новичка. Как правильно начать HTML документ, что бы при открытии его браузером содержимое отображалось корректно. Имею ввиду кодировку. В самом HTML есть еще код РНР... хочется, что бы его вывод тоже был корректен на при открытии браузерами.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: ну или html5 <meta charset=utf-8>

Answer (score 0):

Например, [вот тут](http://html.manual.ru/book/html/hierarchy.php) есть описание...

Ну и [Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_HTML) в помощь :)

Кодировка задаётся непосредственно в теге [META](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)